# <Select> component from material-ui not updating changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The dropdown looks and works fine, but will not update a new selection and I get the following error message:

```
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
```

Selected is not set on `<option>` as far as I'm aware, so it must be set by material-ui's component. Anyway, if I change value into defaultValue, I get the following error message:

```
aterial-UI: the `value` property is required when using the `Select` component with `native=false` (default).
```

I thought it was a problem in Material-ui itself, but their example works fine, although there are no parent/child components in the example like mine.

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/7yk922om7x

My code (shortened for brevity):

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            languageValues: {
                htmlFor: 'lstLanguages',
                value: 'english',
                input: <Input name="language" id="lstLanguages"/>,
                options: [
                    { value: 'dutch', text: 'Nederlands' },
                    { value: 'french', text: 'Français' },
                    { value: 'english', text: 'English' },
                    { value: 'german', text: 'Deutsch' }],
                helperText: 'Choose your language',
            }
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 id="speechTitle">Speech Settings</h2>
                <hr/>
                <FormGroup column='true'>
                    <DropDown
                        dataToFill={ this.state.languageValues }
                        onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) }
                    />
```

Dropdown.js:

```
const DropDown = ({dataToFill}) => {

    const menuItemValueList = dataToFill.options.map((item, i) => {
        return <MenuItem value={ item.value } key={ i }>{ item.text }</MenuItem> //Always provide a key
    })

    return (
        <FormGroup column='true'>
        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor={ dataToFill.htmlFor }>Languages</InputLabel>
            <Select
                defaultValue={ dataToFill.value }
                input={ dataToFill.input }
            >

                { menuItemValueList }
            </Select>
            <FormHelperText>{ dataToFill.helperText }</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
    );
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I think I have found the problem: The `handleChange` function expects `[event.target.name]` but the value that needs changing is nested in the state, I'm not sure how I can access it...

Event handler code:

```
handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    }
```

Nested state object:

```
languageValues: {
            htmlFor: 'lstLanguages',
            value: 'english',
            input: <Input name="language" id="lstLanguages"/>,
            options: [
                { value: 'dutch', text: 'Nederlands' },
                { value: 'french', text: 'Français' },
                { value: 'english', text: 'english' },
                { value: 'german', text: 'German' }
            ],
            helperText: 'Choose your language',
        },
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to why it was giving you the warning? It seems nonsensical and I can't find another thread on the topic.